# How do I create a relationship between two entities using non primary keys?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I have these 2 classes StripeAccount and StripePayout.

```
public class StripeAccount
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string BankName { get; set; }
   public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
   public string Currency { get; set; }
   public string ExternalAccountId { get; set; }
   .
   .
}
public class StripePayout
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
   public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
   public string DestinationId { get; set; }
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
   .
   .
}
```

When I receive and create a new "StripePayout" entity the "DestinationId" is the same as the "ExternalAccountId" from StripeAccount.

When I fetch a users "StripePayouts" I want to query and get some of the values from "StripeAccount"

Ex.

```
var payouts = await _dbContext.StripePayouts.where(p => p.UserId == id)
    .Select(p => new {
        Amount = p.Amount,
        ArrivalDate = p.ArrivalDate,
        BankName = p.StripeAccount.BankName,
        AccountNumber = p.StripeAccount.AccountNumber
 }).ToListAsync()
```

**QUESTION** - How to I create this relationship between "DestinationId" and "ExternalAccountId" using fluent API and what would it look like in the classes?

**UPDATE** - Here is what I tried and found success

I added this to StripeAccount

```
public ICollection<StripePayout> StripePayouts { get; set; }
```

and this to StripePayout under the DestinationId

```
public string BalanceTransactionId { get; set; }
public StripeAccount StripeAccount { get; set; }
```

Then in Fluent API I tried these 2 ways below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StripePayout>()
   .HasOne(a => a.StripeAccount)
   .WithMany(b => b.StripePayouts)
   .HasForeignKey(a => a.DestinationId)
   .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.ExternalAccountId);
```

Comment: If there is a 1:1 relationship between the `Account.Id` and the `Account.ExternalAccountId` (which I presume there must be as your query is looking to get a single `BankName` for the `Payout`) why not write the `Account.Id` to the `Payout` table? Then your relationship can be defined as normal between primary and foreign key.

Comment: No, there isn't a 1:1 between Account.Id and Account.ExternalAccountId

Comment: I'm going to post what I think I need and let me know if it is incorrect.

Comment: So your `Select` won't work then as you can't get a single `Account` for each `Payout` via the `BalanceTransactionId ` / `ExternalAccountId`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question above, but what I can say is that Account.Id and Account. ExternalAccountId are not the same values.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that they are the same values, just that each `Account` with a primary key of `Id` will have a unique `ExternalAccountId`. If that is the case then you can lookup the `Account.Id` based on the `ExternalAccountId` and write that to the `Payout` table.

Comment: It's not possible if `Account.ExternalAccountId` is not unique in `Account` table.

Comment: Account.ExternalAccountId is unique in the Account table

Comment: Since you are targeting different principal key in the account table, you should configure the relationship in the fluent api to target your `ExternalAccountId` . Refer my answer for the syntax

Comment: If it is unique, just add `.HasPrincipalKey(e => e.ExternalAccountId)` to the what you just deleted.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I'll repost what I tried and the errors from the console I received. Give me a sec.

Comment: You need to either :  clear up all the data inside `Payout` table before applying the migration; or setting the BalanceTransactionId as nullable property in the the Payout class by adding ?. Eg: `public string? BalanceTransactionId { get; set; }
public StripeAccount? StripeAccount {get;set;}

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it like this :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Payout>()
            .HasOne<Account>()
            .WithMany<Payout>()
            .HasForeignKey<Payout>(p => p.BalanceTransactionId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.ExternalAccountId);
    }
```

To query the value, you may use this syntax :

```
var payouts = await _dbContext.Payouts.where(p => p.UserId == id)
    .Select(p => new {
        Amount = p.Amount,
        ArrivalDate = p.ArrivalDate,
        BankName = _dbcontext.Accounts.Single(a => p.BalanceTransactionId == a.ExternalAccountId).BankName,
        AccountNumber = _dbcontext.Accounts.Single(a => p.BalanceTransactionId == a.ExternalAccountId).AccountNumber
 }).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: This will create alternate key on `Account.ExternalAccountId`, i.e. the field must be unique and non nullable.

Comment: So it is the supposed behaviour right? I mean  you said that `Account.ExternalAccountId` is unique, so this should work without problem. Or am I am missing something 

Comment: Give me a second to test...

Comment: IDK something isn't correct about your FLuent API code above. Plus aren't you nesting those EF calls, ugh!

Comment: Haha, because in your original question there aren't any of the navigation properties defined in your classes. If you add those navigation properties, then those nested EF called can be removed and we can use your original way of calling the value

Comment: When I tested the Fluent API code I had added the navigation props. I've posted what I tried and what errors I received from the db update.

Comment: I see your update, your new model is now perfect, just need to clear up the existing data inside Payout table before applying the migration

Comment: I only have 1 entry in the Payout table. So I delete it, then which fluent API code do I use?

Comment: Both are equivalent, feel free to choose either one. Since you have only one entry, you can also choose to not delete the entry by just putting a value in that row to match any of the value that already exist in Account table for the ExternalAccountId Column, before applying the migration

Comment: Huh! Wait, I already have a value in the StripePayout table BalanceTransactionId column that matches the ExternalAccountId value in StripeAccount.

Comment: Can you share your migration file when adding the migration?

Comment: After checking your migration, I think everything is perfect, just maybe the existing `ExternalAccountId` in `Account` table is not unique. Maybe there some entries that are currently null, so when migration is applied it will become empty string, and conflicted with each other. It is just my random guess, since I believe everything that you share is correct and fit perfectly

Comment: Ah! I made a small mistake! It's not BalanceTransactionId, it's DestinationId on my StripePayout table that needs the foreign key. Now it migrated and updated the db. Should I make the corrections in my OP above?

Comment: I think ya, so future people can understand it better haha. But does the problem gone?

Comment: Yes the problem is gone. It's late here, 2:00 AM my eyes are seeing lots of long id numbers, so I was looking at the wrong ids. I'll post my corrections.